# Leave a div with width in pixels and the other divs in percentage

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

You see, is that I want to make the div 2 have a fixed width and is responsive only the div 1 and div 3. See if someone can guide me or tell me some way to do how could leave the div 2 in pixels and others in percentage?

When reducing the resolution will be the div 1 and div 3 to be made smaller, but the div 2 remains at a fixed size.

Is there any way to do this?

[image: Here you have an overview of how the structure would]

I have tried in this way, but the div 3 to make smaller reesolución 3 to move the div below. I wish it did not happen and that the Div 2 remain the same size and it was div 3 which size cringe when making smaller resolution.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1014px) {       
    #div2 { 
        width: 22%;
        min-width: 196px;           
    }

    #div3 {
        width: 78%;
    }

    #div1 {
        width: 100%;    
    }
}
```

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: How to code => ask Google. Why the code does not work => ask SO

Comment: Thanks I edited the message. I gave inadvertently send when he had not yet completed. I have removed many points uff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use `calc` to set the width at a percent whilst using the sidebar width as a minus value on the section 3.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.header {
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}
.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  background: grey;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}
.main {
  height: 100%;
  background: orange;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
}
```

```html
<div class="header">1</div>
<div class="sidebar">2</div>
<div class="main">3</div>
```

Comment: YESSSSSSSSSSS !!!!!!!  know the property CALC and see that I have investigated by google. It is barbaric thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Very simple. Just make the div 2 float left and add desired width. Then give same amount of margin left to div 3 as the width of div 2. See below code.

```
<div style="background:green;height:30px;"></div>
<div style="background:red;height:100px;float:left; width:200px;"></div>
<div style="background:grey;height:100px;margin-left:200px;"></div>
```

See this **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d9wjswm0/)**.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help too :D

Comment: Amazing. There are several ways to achieve this. I spent all afternoon yesterday looking for a solution. Sometimes google is a double-edged sword. Thank you !!

Comment: Approach always matters. I like to keep things simple.

Answer (score 1):

hope this will help you.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zLu5vx7u/

Html

```
    <header>1</header>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">2</div>
    <div class="right-content">3</div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    *{margin:0;padding:0;}
    header{background-color:#000; height:50px;}
   body{background-color:red; font-size:50px; color:#FFF;}
   .wrapper{position:relative;}
.left{position:fixed; width:250px;background-color:#ccc;
  min-eight:100%}
  .right-content{position:relative;padding-left:250px;}
```

Comment: Great, I keep the example in case I was needed. Thank you !!